# Custom validating a Model object in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I I need to validate some thing in mvc in my controller I have to

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.somestring)// in the view

if (model.string = some condition)
ModelState.AddModelError("somestring", "String cannot be empty");// in the controller
```

but if in my view I have a custom object like

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.someobject.somestring)// in the view
```

how do I validate it? Is the following syntax correct?

```
if (model.someobject.somestring = some condition)
ModelState.AddModelError("somestring", "String cannot be empty");// in the controller
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure the full path to your property is used when specifying your key:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("someobject.somestring", "String cannot be empty);
```